# Замена синонимов по шаблону PHP

Tags: php, парсер

Есть ряд синонимов, которые заменяются на нужные словоформы:

```
<?php

$sostav_result = "камень";
$sostav_result = "бурый камень дробленый";
$sostav_result = mb_strtolower($sostav_result);

//Словарь
$sostav_result = preg_replace('/\bкамень\b/u', "камень бурый", $sostav_result);
$sostav_result = preg_replace('/\bбурый камень дробленый\b/u', "камень бурый", $sostav_result);

echo $sostav_result;
```

**Ожидаемый результат**: *камень бурый*

**Получаемый результат**: *бурый камень бурый дробленый*

Логические ошибки понятны. Но не понятно пока, **как решить задачу**: не менять отдельные слова из фразы.

***Живой пример***:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/799bccffaee5e4a367eea7fa0cd9f693eed7d9ca

Comment: у вас есть фраза "бурый камень дробленый" потом регуляркой вы заменяете камень на камень бурый и у вас выходит "бурый камень бурый дробленый" вторая регулярка у вас не проходит потому что в фразе "бурый камень бурый дробленый" нет "бурый камень дробленый" в итоге вы и получаете "бурый камень бурый дробленый"

Comment: @madfan41k это я понимаю, спасибо. В том и стоит вопрос - как можно сделать иначе?

Comment: @Эдуард если один вариант, то да. При нескольких разных (как в примере) происходит процесс подмены (как верно описал madfan41k в первом комментарии)

Comment: @Amsterdam вероятно, нужно искать вхождения по якорям: [Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0c3e1bfe5e60edb4ec9da6ef163da393f002b012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте местами порядок замены синонимов. Сначала, более частные случаи замены "бурый камень дробленый" меняете на тэг1, привязанный к первому случаю, потом уже более общие "" меняете на тэг2, привязанный ко второму случаю  (если они попадутся). Потом меняете теги на необходимые слова-замены.

Comment: Дело в том, что возможности размещать упорядоченно синонимы - нет. Они могу добавляться автоматически и дополнять словарь в последовательном порядке по факту добавления

Comment: Логично фразы/слова-замены вытаскивать из справочника с сортировкой по длине символов в обратном порядке.

Comment: В целом, как вариант, подходит